# Segmented sieve programs crashes

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the [SPOJ, PRIME1 - Prime Generator](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) problem, I tried this in segmented sieve in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LEN 31624

char temp[LEN];

void sieve_of_eratosthenes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; temp[i] = '1', i++){}
    for (int i = 2; i <= 178; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] != '0')
            for (int x = i+i ; x < LEN; temp[x] = '0', x += i){}   
    }
}

int main()
{
    sieve_of_eratosthenes();    
    int T;
    scanf("%i",&T);

    while (T--)
    {
        long long int m;
        long long int n;

        scanf("%lli %lli",&m,&n);

        char main_primes[n-m+1];

        for (long long int i = 0; i < n+m-1; main_primes[i] = '1', i++){}
    
        for (long long int i = 2; i*i < n; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == '1')
            {
                long long int base = i*i;

                if (base < m)
                    base = ((m+i-1) / i) *i;

                for (long long int x = base; x <= n; main_primes[x-m] = '0', x += i){}
            } 
        }
        for (long long int i = 0; i < n-m+1; i++)
        {
            if (main_primes[i] == '1' && i+m != 1)
                printf("%lli\n",i+m);
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I can't understand if I give input over 10 (like 11 and 20), the program crashes and show this error

```
0 [main] PRIME1_Prime_Generator 557 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to PRIME1_Prime_Generator.exe.stackdump
```

I can't understand why it's happening, what's wrong??

Comment: `char main_primes[n-m+1];` and `i < n+m-1` aren't quite the same.

Comment: Aside: `memset` would be more efficient instead of that loop too.

Comment: @WeatherVane something easy can be optimized by the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/8zPsv1aqh but the `memset` is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This line produces an invalid write:

```
for (long long int i = 0; i < n+m-1; main_primes[i] = '1', i++){}
```

The bound `n+m-1` is larger than the amount of memory allocated (i.e. `n-m+1`) in the statement before it.